# TSQL count rows for group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need the count of rows after the group by.

```
SELECT COUNT(CheckNumber)
FROM myTable
WHERE Status = 'Good'
GROUP BY CheckNumber
```

Results:

```
Row 1 = 1
Row 2 = 15
Row 3 = 5
```

I also tried using DISTINCT

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CheckNumber)
FROM myTable
WHERE Status = 'Good'
GROUP BY CheckNumber
```

Results:

```
Row 1 = 1
Row 2 = 1
Row 3 = 1
```

I want the results to be 3

Comment: Could you provide the data that you have on 'myTable' , and why are you expecting a 3 as result?

Comment: what does the count tell you by itself and without an identifier for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the GROUP BY is entirely redundant based on what you say you want. Why not just:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct CheckNumber) 
FROM myTable
WHERE Status = 'Good'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
   SELECT COUNT(CheckNumber)
   FROM myTable
   WHERE Status = 'Good'
   GROUP BY CheckNumber
) as myData
```

This should give you your total of 3 as requested.